# HTTPPOST request in Salesforce is failing when I run in JDK 7 but works fine in JDK 8

Tags: rest-api, httppost

I am receiving a two different response for below HTTPPOST request based on the JDK version. On JDK 1.7 it says BAD Request, I am not able to understand the difference in those two responses. Could you please help me to understand the issue?

---

Reference: [Verify the REST Environment (REST-Based APIs)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_verify_rest.htm)

**Request:**

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

/* Assemble the login request URL */
String loginURL = LOGINURL +
                  GRANTSERVICE +
                  "&client_id=" + CLIENTID +
                  "&client_secret=" + CLIENTSECRET +
                  "&username=" + USERNAME +
                  "&password=" + PASSWORD;
/* POST Login requests */
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginURL);

HttpResponse response = null;
/* Execute the login POST request */
response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
/* verify response is HTTP OK */
final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
{
    System.out.println("Error authenticating to Force.com: " + statusCode);
    // Error is in EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())
    return;
}
```

**Response (JDK 1.8):**

```
HttpResponseProxy {
    HTTP / 1.1 200 OK
    [
        Date : Fri, 21 Oct 2016 10 : 12 : 38 GMT,
        Strict - Transport - Security : max - age = 31536000;
        includeSubDomains,
        Set - Cookie : BrowserId = 3A1ryE8eQa6O - AqbTHyJqQ;
        Path = /;
        Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Tue, 20-Dec-2016 10:12:38 GMT,
        Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT,
        Pragma: no-cache,
        Cache-Control: no-cache,
        no-store, 
        X-ReadOnlyMode: false,
        Content-Type: application/json;
        charset = UTF - 8,
        Transfer - Encoding : chunked
    ]
    org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity @ 892d68
}
```

**Response (JDK 1.7):**

```
HttpResponseProxy {
    HTTP / 1.1 400 Bad Request
    [
        Date : Fri, 21 Oct 2016 10 : 22 : 05 GMT,
        Strict - Transport - Security : max - age = 31536000;
        includeSubDomains,
        Set - Cookie : BrowserId = tbJli6t8SyCbA6I8eA0vow;
        Path = /;
        Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Tue, 20-Dec-2016 10:22:05 GMT,
        Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT,
        Pragma: no-cache,
        Cache-Control: no-cache,
        no-store,
        X-ReadOnlyMode: false,
        Content-Type: application/json;
        charset = UTF - 8,
        Transfer - Encoding : chunked
    ]
    ResponseEntityProxy {
        [
            Content - Type : application / json;
            charset = UTF - 8, Chunked : true
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@superfell I got solution. Following code did the job for me.
Thanks to you who pushed me in the right direction.

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    SSLContext.getDefault(),
                    new String[] { "SSLv2Hello","SSLv3","TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"},
                    null,
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                    .register("https", socketFactory)
                    .build();

            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).build();
```

Reference: [Enable TLSv1.2 for Apache HTTPClients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608243/how-to-enable-sslv3-with-apache-httpclient)

Answer (score 1):

The response body should give you more details, but given the works/fails based on JDK version, I'd say you're hitting a TLS 1.2 required problem. You'll need to either stick to JDK 1.8 [where TLS 1.2 is enabled by default], or if you need to support JDK 1.7 as well, then there are flags to enable TLS 1.2 support there, there are details in the [KB Article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207).

Comment: can you help me with the code. I tried all the code possible mentioned in the article. Still no success.

Comment: You'll have to check the docs for the http library you're using. Also you should really consider just not using JDK 1.7, its already 1 year past its end of life. https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml

Comment: Yeah, when support for TLS 1.0 was dropped a lot of integrations broke :)